# How to convert a JSON array into a set of rows in Oracle?

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c, oracle18c

I want to convert a json array into a set of rows in Oracle.

Input:

```
'["a","b","c"]'
```

Output:

```
col_name
---------
a
b
c
```

PostgreSQL provides the function, *jsonb_array_elements(jsonb)* to do this.

How can I do this in Oracle 18c. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `JSON_TABLE`

```
SELECT value
FROM json_table( (select js from samp) , '$[*]'
                COLUMNS (value PATH '$')
               )
```

*Replace **js** with your columnname & **samp** with your tablename in the above query*

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c500a65e3acb7b86e28acb9c2918011d)